# How to pass a column name into apply

Tags: r

I have a function within a `apply` function that requires a column name. How do I pass a column name in an `apply` function?

The aim is to find out how to pass column names into a function contained within `apply` function rather than an easy way to print all the column names

I have tried:
`apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) print(names(x)))`  which gives me a list of lists where each row is the column name and each column is the title of a datapoint. I just want to print each column name once from the original dataset.

Comment: What is the issue with that code?.  Please show a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: `apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) print(names(x)))` works fine. I'm confused about what you want - you are `apply`ing to rows, so each row will have every column name...

Comment: @akrun see further explanation. if I run with applying to each column then I get a print of the whole dataset rather than just all the column names which is what I want

Comment: What is the issue in `colnames` if you want to print only once

Comment: If you just want to print each column name once, why are you using `apply`? Use `names(x)` by itself.

Comment: See paragraph two. I've kept it simple to just find out how I can pass column names. I will replace print with another more complex function later

Comment: Do you want to apply a function to each column (name) of a data frame?

Comment: I can't tell what you want at all. I think your example is too simple. You say you "just want to print each column name **once**", so use `print(names(x))` or just `names(x)`. But then you want to use `apply`, which runs a function on each row, so **more than once** (assuming you have more than one row). You don't provide sample input or desired output. What are we to do? I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Daniel. Yes that is correct.

Comment: See `?apply`. `MARGIN = 1` (like you have in the question) applies functions to each row. `MARGIN = 2` applies functions to each column. If you have a data frame, not a matrix, then `sapply` or `lapply` will also apply functions to each column.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do an `lapply` and still know the name of the respective column that is being worked on inside the function used.

Then you would probably do

```
lapply(colnames(mtcars), function(x) {
  if (x == "mpg")
    diff(mtcars[[x]])
  else
    cumsum(mtcars[[x]])
})
```

Comment: indeed as Roland points out: as a general approach you can iterate over the list/data frame NAMES (rather than the items themselves) and then subset the list by the name to retrieve the item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like `lapply(colnames(mtcars), print)`? This returns the result as list, but depending on your required return value, you can use one of the `purrr::map_*()` functions, e.g.:

```
purrr::map_chr(colnames(mtcars), ~ .x)
#>  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
#> [11] "carb"
```

Comment: OK. Well this will be an introduction to purr for me